# Universal app built for Win 8.1 - OAuth 2.0 Azure support

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, oauth-2.0, win-universal-app

I have a Universal app built for Windows 8.1 using Visual studio 2015. (This was done before UWP, there are 2 separate projects for phones and others. But we are not actually using the phone version anymore)

[image]

The client wants to add OAuth 2.0 authentication with Windows Azure DS to this app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

I am bit worried, since this app is some what old, will there be any issues doing that? Will it be supported?

If supported will the code be the same as for doing this for a UWP app done using VS 2017 or 2019 or will there be changes.

Because we need to do the same for another UWP app built with VS2017 as well. So do you think we will be able to use the same code in both apps or will there be differences due to version differences?

Any guidance on this is really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Whether it's Win8.1 or Win10, you can complete OAuth authorization by sending a network request. And you have the same problem in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/1291/universal-app-built-for-win-81-oauth-20-azure-supp.html?childToView=1301#answer-1301), where I have a more detailed answer.

Comment: Yeah, you can use the device code flow with just HTTP support. A nicer alternative is to use the authorization code flow, but that requires the ability to open a browser and read the URL to get the code when the user has logged in.